# Problem at installation at my pc

Tags: installation

I have a problem when installing Blender in my PC. Not about when executing the aplication, but in the installation.
When i tried to install, there is a massage "Another installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one." although i'm not installing anything except this software. What should i do?

Comment: This is more of an issue with the operating system, not Blender. Reboot your PC, if that doens't solve it just use the portable zipped setups, no install required.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue with the operating system, not Blender itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably cancel the installation and reboot your PC, to make sure no installation is running. Then try to install, just for the sake of trying to get a "clean" installation, with nothing interfering.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to turn off your antivirus, Wifi or LAN (Internet connection).
Second, Restart your PC.
Then try to install it once more (in condition your antivirus & Internet connection still turn off).